# ASP.NET authentication not working on Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, authentication

I have created an  bootstrap website with a simple admin page for some results of the main page.
Everything is working correctly on FireFox and Chrome, but when i'm trying to login via Internet Explorer, everytime I enter the credentials and click my login button, i'm keep getting redirected to the login page.

Web.config:

```
    <!-- Authentication -->
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/beheer/login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" defaultUrl="~/beheer/default.aspx" path="beheer">
        <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
          <!-- Login en wachtwoord -->
          <user name="beheerder" password="beheerder"/>
        </credentials>
      </forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>

  </system.web>

  <!-- Toegangscontrole beheer overzicht -->
  <location path="beheer">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Global.asax:

```
static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
    routes.MapPageRoute("beheer", "beheer", "~/beheer/default.aspx");
} /* RegisterRoutes */
```

Login.aspx.cs:

```
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            String LoginGebruikersnaam = NameTextBox.Text;
            String LoginPaswoord = PasswordTextBox.Text;

            if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(LoginGebruikersnaam, LoginPaswoord)) {
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(LoginGebruikersnaam, this.RememberMeCheckBox.Checked);
            } else {
                this.FoutmeldingPlaceHolder.Visible = true;
            }
        } /* LoginButton_Click */
```

Does someone knows the answer to this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053394/asp-net-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-loop-for-ie-7-8-and-11-but-n. Is your IE version on login test matches with existing question?

Comment: I have it on every IE version (Edge, 10,9,8,7,5).

Comment: Maybe IE renders your website in compatibility mode?

Comment: @TasosK. no it doenst

Comment: Have you checked this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179500/problem-with-asp-net-forms-authentication-in-internet-explorer)? Seems that it has a few decent answers

Comment: @TasosK. I have, but not really helping me :(

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
I had to move my login page to the root of the website.